# How to pick hours/minutes in airbnb react-dates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dates

I want to not only pick dates but also hours and minutes with airbnb react-dates, does react-dates have such an API to handle this?

Comment: as far as i can see there is no api for handling hours & minutes
https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates

Answer (score 2):

It is not yet possible. A [request has been made](https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates/issues/255) to include a date picker. Still no answer from  airbnb :)